# How can i get XML tag value?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <deviceType>urn:roku-com:device:player:1-0</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>Roku Streaming Stick 4K+</friendlyName>
```

Here is the code snippet where i want to get value of tag  friendlyName please help i am to android development...

Comment: @404NotFound yes got it thank you so much !!